# Arrow RecordBatch as Polars DataFrame

Tags: rust, odbc, apache-arrow, rust-polars

I often need to fetch large quantities of data from Microsoft SQL servers to be manipulated with Polars in Rust, and per enterprise security policy am more or less forced to use ODBC for these connections. The ODBC requirement restricts me from using mature and featureful libraries like ConnectorX. I am able to connect and efficiently read query results into RecordBatch objects from Arrow using arrow_odbc, but have not been able to convert these RecordBatch objects into Polars DataFrames.

Because the actual data component of `RecordBatch` and `Series` have the same underlying representation, I thought it would be possible to create a `DataFrame` from a `RecordBatch` zero-copy.

However in `columns.push(Series::from_arrow(&schema.fields().get(i).unwrap().name(), *column)?);` I get the error:

```
mismatched types
expected struct `std::boxed::Box<(dyn polars::export::polars_arrow::array::Array + 'static)>`
   found struct `Arc<dyn arrow::array::Array>`
```

I was under the impression that an `Arc<dyn Array>` is an `ArrayRef`, is the real problem perhaps that I have an `Arc<dyn arrow::array::Array>` and `Series::from_arrow()` is expecting a Polars `Arc<Array>`? If so, how do I resolve that?

My full code is below for reference.

```
use arrow_odbc::{odbc_api::{Environment, ConnectionOptions}, OdbcReaderBuilder};
use arrow::record_batch::RecordBatch;
use polars::prelude::*;
use anyhow::Result;

const CONNECTION_STRING: &str = "...";

pub fn test() -> Result<()> {

    let odbc_environment = Environment::new()?;
     
    let connection = odbc_environment.connect_with_connection_string(
        CONNECTION_STRING,
        ConnectionOptions::default()
    )?;

    let cursor = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM Backcast_Power_Plant_Map", ())?.unwrap();

    let arrow_record_batches = OdbcReaderBuilder::new().build(cursor)?;

    fn record_batch_to_dataframe(batch: &RecordBatch) -> Result<DataFrame, PolarsError> {
        let schema = batch.schema();
        let mut columns = Vec::with_capacity(batch.num_columns());
        for (i, column) in batch.columns().iter().enumerate() {
            columns.push(Series::from_arrow(&schema.fields().get(i).unwrap().name(), *column)?);
        }
        Ok(DataFrame::from_iter(columns))
    }

    for batch in arrow_record_batches {
        dbg!(record_batch_to_dataframe(&batch?));
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears `polars` and `arrow-odbc` uses different arrow crates: `polars` uses [`polars-arrow`](https://docs.rs/polars-arrow), and `arrow-odbc` uses [`arrow`](https://docs.rs/arrow). The former's array type is [`Box<dyn polars_arrow::array::Array>`](https://docs.rs/polars-arrow/latest/polars_arrow/array/trait.Array.html), while the latter has the type [`ArrayRef`](https://docs.rs/arrow/latest/arrow/array/type.ArrayRef.html), which is an alias for [`Arc<dyn arrow::array::Array>`](https://docs.rs/arrow/latest/arrow/array/trait.Array.html).

Luckily for us, there exists a compatibility layer in the `polars-arrow` crate. You can convert between the two types (and more) via `From` impls:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use arrow::record_batch::RecordBatch;
use arrow_odbc::{
    odbc_api::{ConnectionOptions, Environment},
    OdbcReaderBuilder,
};
use polars::prelude::*;

const CONNECTION_STRING: &str = "...";

pub fn test() -> Result<()> {
    let odbc_environment = Environment::new()?;

    let connection = odbc_environment
        .connect_with_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING, ConnectionOptions::default())?;

    let cursor = connection
        .execute("SELECT * FROM Backcast_Power_Plant_Map", ())?
        .unwrap();

    let arrow_record_batches = OdbcReaderBuilder::new().build(cursor)?;

    fn record_batch_to_dataframe(batch: &RecordBatch) -> Result<DataFrame, PolarsError> {
        let schema = batch.schema();
        let mut columns = Vec::with_capacity(batch.num_columns());
        for (i, column) in batch.columns().iter().enumerate() {
            let arrow = Box::<dyn polars_arrow::array::Array>::from(&**column);
            columns.push(Series::from_arrow(
                &schema.fields().get(i).unwrap().name(),
                arrow,
            )?);
        }
        Ok(DataFrame::from_iter(columns))
    }

    for batch in arrow_record_batches {
        dbg!(record_batch_to_dataframe(&batch?));
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Note this requires `polars-arrow` with the `arrow_rs` feature as a dependency.

From what I can tell, this does not copy the actual data.

Comment: After lining up the dependency version and the standalone version of polars-arrow that worked perfectly and the memory profile certainly looks like no copying is occuring, thanks. What would have been the best way for me to sus out that Polars didn't actually rely on the arrows crate for my own knowledge? Just drilling down through the impls?

Comment: @PatBlinds Clicking out through docs.rs functions and traits... At least that's how I did it.