Convert Arrow Data to Polars DataFrame
I'm trying to pass arrow data returned from a clickhouse query to a polars dataframe.
One problem that I had was trying to convert Arc to Box which is one of the dtype parameters in from_arrow.
What would be an efficient way of reading in Arrow data to a polars dataframe?
Is there a native way to read in a arrow query in polars (similar to parquet / feather)?
Here is a simlar stackoverflow question.
Trying to accomplish reading in 'record_batches' vector into a dataframe.
use std::error::Error;
use arrow::ipc::reader::FileReader;
use std::io::Cursor;
use reqwest::Client as HttpClient;

// use clickhouse::Client;
// use polars::prelude::*;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    //columns().await?;
    factor_returns_arrow().await?;
    Ok(())
}

async fn factor_returns_arrow() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let clickhouse_url = "http://localhost:8000"; 
    let query = "SELECT * FROM factor_returns FORMAT Arrow";
    let client = HttpClient::new();
    let response = client.get(clickhouse_url)
        .query(&[("query", query)])
        .send()
        .await?;
    
    if response.status().is_success() {
        let bytes = response.bytes().await?;
        let cursor = Cursor::new(bytes);
        let mut reader = FileReader::try_new(cursor, None)?;
        
        let schema = reader.schema();
        let fields = schema.fields();

        let _column_names = fields.iter().map(|field| field.name()).collect::<Vec<_>>();

        let mut record_batches = Vec::new(); // **<--- Reading into Polars**
        
        while let Some(batch_result) = reader.next() {
            let batch = batch_result?;
            record_batches.push(batch);
        }

        
        println!("{:?}", record_batches);
        
    } else {
        eprintln!("Error: {:?}", response.status());
    }
    
    Ok(())
}


arrow and polars-arrow are not the same thing. Can you use polars-arrow instead? If not, do https://stackoverflow.com/a/78916692/7884305 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/78084066/7884305 answer your question?

Hi @ChayimFriedman thank you for pointing it out! This does answer my question and I was able to successfully convert the Arrow data to a polars df. I'll add what worked for me.
Thanks!

After installing polars-arrow, I was able to create a separate function to convert the arrow data to a polars dataframe.
I used a similar function from Arrow RecordBatch as Polars DataFrame.
async fn factor_returns_arrow() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let clickhouse_url = "http://localhost:8000"; 
    let query = "SELECT * FROM factor_exposures FORMAT Arrow";
    let client = HttpClient::new();
    let response = client.get(clickhouse_url)
        .query(&[("query", query)])
        .send()
        .await?;
    
    if response.status().is_success() {
        let bytes = response.bytes().await?;
        let cursor = Cursor::new(bytes);
        let mut reader = FileReader::try_new(cursor, None)?;
        
        let mut lazy_frames = Vec::new();
        
        while let Some(batch_result) = reader.next() {
            let batch = batch_result?;
            let df = record_batch_to_dataframe(&batch)?;
            lazy_frames.push(df.lazy());
        }
        
        if lazy_frames.len() > 1 {
            let combined_df = concat(lazy_frames, UnionArgs::default())?.collect()?;
            println!("{}", combined_df);

        } else if let Some(lazy_df) = lazy_frames.first() {
            let df = lazy_df.clone().collect()?;
            println!("{}", df);
        }
        
    } else {
        eprintln!("Error: {:?}", response.status());
    }
    
    Ok(())
}

fn record_batch_to_dataframe(batch: &RecordBatch) -> Result<DataFrame, PolarsError> {
    let schema = batch.schema();
    let columns = batch
        .columns()
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, column)| {
        Series::from_arrow(schema.field(i).name(), column.clone().into())
    }).collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>();
    
    DataFrame::new(columns?)
}

